# Is the convergence limit of subsequences of weakly convergent sequences unique?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

i have seen a paper and it claimes that some point is a convex combination of limit points of a sequence, but if a sequence has a limit, the limit is unique. So i'm confused about the "combination of the limit point".
The paper's link is https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0304406879900132, and the claim is proposition C.

Comment: There are two different types of convergences involved in Proposition C.  One is weak convergence with respect to an $L^{p}$-norm topology; the other is pointwise convergence.  Hence there is no contradiction to the "limits are unique" maxim.

Comment: But different types of convergence have the same limit,  so there is only one point？